# custom events in backbone

Tags: events, backbone.js, daterangepicker

```
$('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
});
```

How do I call this as a Backbone event?

Comment: wondering whether the answer helped...

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you're using is for [jquery-ui](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui) which is based on [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). Since backbone uses jQuery for delegating `DOM` events, you should be able to handle this in the normal backbone way, assuming the plugin uses normal jQuery events:

```
events:{
 'apply.daterangepicker input[name="datefilter"]': 'handler'
},
handler: function(){}
```